# How to send scsi write commands to a SSD in a Kernel Module

Tags: linux, solid-state-drive, scsi

I try to write as fast as possible on a SSD. It's very important to have synchronous writes, because we need to know if the data is power failures safe written.

I thought about sending scsi commands on my own, to avoid most of the Linux Kernel Block IO Stack (which is not needed in our usecase).
To avoid Kernel Entry/Exit overhead, it should be a Kernel Module.

- Do you know an example how to send scsi writes to a device?
- How would you implement this?
- Or why is the scsi layer the wrong entrypoint?

Answer (score 0):

Typical access to device is to make use of Block IO Stack, if you intend to avoid that IO stack, and write device directly, you need to write your own low level driver for your SCSI HBA(on which your SSD is connected) on Linux.

What's more, I think Linux Kernel Block IO Stack won't affect much on your test.